# How to handle a webrequest POST server side

Tags: java, web-services, post

I'm new to webserver work. I am trying to make a webrequest POST from a C# client to my Java webservice. I believe the POST is being done successfully but I do not know how to tell the server to retrieve and use the POST data.

This is my code in Java right now:

```
//import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.iharder.encoders.Base64;
import com.google.zxing.*;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource;
import com.google.zxing.common.HybridBinarizer;

@Service("FCBarcodeRecognitionService")
public class DecodeBarcodeFromImageActivity extends Activity {

  private static final Log LOG = LogFactory
              .getLog(DecodeBarcodeFromImageActivity.class);

  @Operation("DecodeBarcodeFromImage")
  @Documentation("Attempt to decode a barcode from POST image data.\n  Returns a String of the decoded barcode and the type\n  of barcode detected if successful.")
  public DecodeFromImageOutput enact(DecodeFromImageInput input)
    throws DependencyException {

       DecodeFromImageOutput output = new DecodeFromImageOutput();
       LOG.debug("Received DecodeFromBarcodeImage request..."); 
       // Decode the images from the String arguments. They could
       // potentially be in any encoding format. (e.g. Base64)
       //How do I retrieve the POST data to use inside this operation??

       //I have something like this now
       ImageEncoder imageEncoder = new ImageEncoder();
       //the current input is just something I'm manually giving it. I want it to be the encoded image from the POST data
       List<BufferedImage> bufferedImgs = imageEncoder.decodeImageData(input);
       LOG.debug("Received " + bufferedImgs.size() + " images from decoder.");

       // Attempt to read a barcode (this will just pass the POST data, once I get it to my decode method)
       try {
           DecodedBarcode barcode = recognizeBarcodeFromImages(input, bufferedImgs);
           output.setDecodedBarcode(barcode);
```

This is my code in C# right now:
//I am trying to POST an encoded (base64) image

```
WebRequest serverReq = WebRequest.Create("http://saxtonl.desktop.amazon.com:8000/explorer");
serverReq.Method = "POST";
serverReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
serverReq.ContentLength = base64String.Length;
Stream dataStream = serverReq.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
dataStream.Close();
WebResponse serverRsp = serverReq.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)serverRsp).StatusDescription);
dataStream = serverRsp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
serverRsp.Close();
```

Comment: Hi eex and welcome to [so], can you post some sample code as I've indicated in the above "edit"? You should be able to find the gray "edit" link to the lower left of the post, and be able to add new code via that mechanism.

Comment: I've added the c# code in that is making the Post request. I did not include the code encoding the image but can if that is necessary. I do not really have much in Java on the server - as I said I do not know how to retrieve/access the encoded images once it is posted.

Comment: Are you using a specific java framework here? Or do you pretty much need to know exactly how to start on the java side?

Comment: A good idea where to start/general overview would be very helpful. Once I get the POST data I will be able to use it in the operation fine, I just don't understand how the POST method works on the server end/how to get my encoded image

Comment: Added some more Java code that I have. Not sure how to adapt it to use the POST data. Something like StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder(); BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();? I'm still lost on getting/using the POST data on the server